# How to add a class name to ul li in angular 11

Tags: typescript, angular11

Tried to add a class name like active to ul li using div class name wrapper. But, It is not working. How to access the class name to add a class name to ul li in typescript. I do not know how to do it. So, please help to find the solution.

app.component.html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<ul>
<li class="active">test1</li>
<li>test2</li>
<li>test3</li>
</ul>
</div>

<button (click)="activeTab('test1')"> Test 1 </button>
<button (click)="activeTab('test2')"> Test 2 </button>
<button (click)="activeTab('test3')"> Test 3 </button>
```

app.component.ts

```
  activeTab(tabname: any) {
      let el = this.elRef.nativeElement
               .querySelector(".wrapper")
               .querySelector("ul")
               .querySelectorAll("li");
         el.forEach(name => {
            console.log(name.innerHTML);
            var tname = name.innerHTML;
      if (tname == tabname) {
         this.renderer.addClass(el, "active");
      } else {
         this.renderer.removeClass(el, "active");
      }
      });
  }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nwycmk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Angular is essentially an MVC platform. Interacting directly with the DOM like that is not recommended. Instead, change your model, and have your view react to the model change.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: I am using angular11 not angular1.x

Comment: The [angular] tag is for Angular 2+. The [angularjs] tag is for Angular JS 1.x.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a `currentTab` property in your `component.ts` and bind it to the `[ngClass]` directive. Something like that.

...component.ts

```
currentTab: number = 1;
```

...component.html

```
<li [ngClass]="{'active': currentTab===1}">test1</li>
<li [ngClass]="{'active': currentTab===2}">test2</li>
<li [ngClass]="{'active': currentTab===3}">test3</li>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8pmavr?file=src/app/app.component.html)